# How to remove an array element with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I managed to pull a string element from My_array then remove it temporarily till the next browser refresh but how to remove it completely so that element is completely gone?

```
<script>
Array.prototype.randsplice = function() {
    var ri = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.length);
    var rs = this.splice(ri, 1);
    return rs;
};

var my_array = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G'];
var result = my_array.randsplice();

document.write(result);
document.write("<hr>");
document.write(my_array);
```

Comment: Uhhh... reloading the page wipes anything you've done in the current one. You'll need to use storage, eg. `localStorage`.

Comment: On every browser refresh, you will get same set of array, unless you use some kind storage like cookies or server side storage

Comment: You can use cookies as local storage and on every browser refresh fetch data from this cookie. Also note that, this data is stored till the browser history/cookies is not cleared. Checkout https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie

Comment: Right, of course! so simple.... Thanks,

Comment: Exactly was was I was looking for. Thanks trupti.